# Workflow : test if a value is empty

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, conditional

I would like to start some actions in a workflow when a field doesn't have any value, when it doesn't have already been filled out.

But when I choose the condition `if a value is equal to a value`, I don't know how to set the second value to empty.

Comment: Maybe here some ideas: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/112c2be9-5d3e-47d1-ad1c-06312de8a925/workflow-condition-assigned-to-is-not-empty?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: In fact I never understood that I could click on equal and put empty instead, so it's ok. thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just needed to set `is empty` instead of `is equal to`. I just didn't know we could do that.

Comment: Depends on the field type, but yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Create a second field, set it hidden in the form, and compare both..

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. This doesn't answer the question as per StackExchange standards. Check this [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and a don't set it to anything, then use that as "null." If you need a null date, check for less than or equal to 1/1/1900 12:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

For some types of fields, this is as simple as clicking `equals` in the condition and then select `is empty` from the drop-down.

If `is empty` is not in the drop-down, however, you need to create a temporary workflow variable and set the field's value to the variable, and then you can test if the variable `is empty`.